# Checking for a value of a Future

Tags: scala, future

I want to check whether or not a Future `f` is completed right now by looking at a value its holding. That is not about

```
f onComplete {

}
```

It's about checking a value it's holding currently without blocking.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
f.value match {
  case Some(Success(x)) => println(s"the future is completed successfully with value $x")
  case Some(Failure(e)) => println(s"the future failed with an error: $e")
  case None => println("the future has not yet completed")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [value](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future) if it is None the Future is not completed. If it is Some some will contain the value.

Answer (score 1):

You could always call f.isCompleted

That will return true if the result is available.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future